# Can't include files with PHP

Tags: php, nginx, windows-server-2003

I've a WEMP server with PHP 5.3.28 installed on a Windows Server 2003.
Everything works, except for `require`, I've in my script.

This is the relevant code:

```
<?
require('info.php');
echo 'root directory require<br>';
require('subpath/info.php');
echo 'sub directory require<br>';
```

The problem is that the require of the `info.php` located in the root directory works, but the one in the sub-directory doesn't.

The script breaks on the first `require()` which contains a sub-directory without throw errors.

I've checked that PHP have permissions to read the sub-directory trying with `file_exists()` and `file_get_contents()` and everything works flawlessly.

No errors are reported in the Nginx log or PHP log.
How can I fix this problem?

NB: The same script on my WEMP server installed on my workstation with Windows 7 works.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
require 'subpath'.DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR.'info.php';
```

Comment: Doesn't work, even because it would not work with the other commands as well.

Comment: Ah, and the same script works on my local installation on Windows 7.